# PHP how to map json with element name in form something:something:something

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to map a json file to a mysql database see [undefined index Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022131/undefined-index-name) for code

the problem I believe is that there is no value for either element from the 3rd entry but there is a value called aws:autoscaling:groupName

I am just wondering how I should go about declaring this is it the same or does the colons make a difference as using the method in the aforementioned question fails due to not finding index as per the previous question thanks

my json or at least the important bits

```
{  
"fileVersion":"1.0",
"configurationItems":[  
{  
 "configurationItemVersion":"1.0",
 "configurationItemCaptureTime":"2014-12-05T10:22:51.751Z",
 "configurationStateId":1,
 "relatedEvents":[  ],
 "awsAccountId":"",
 "configurationItemStatus":"ResourceDiscovered",
 "resourceId":"",
 "ARN":"",
 "awsRegion":"",
 "availabilityZone":"",
 "configurationStateMd5Hash":"",
 "resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
 "resourceCreationTime":"2014-01-06T10:37:37.000Z",
 "tags":{  
    "Name":"dbn.prod-us.wordeo.com",
    "cirrushq_id":"instance_20"
 },
 "relationships":[  ],
 "configuration":{  }
  },
  {  
 "configurationItemVersion":"1.0",
 "configurationItemCaptureTime":"2014-12-05T10:22:51.751Z",
 "configurationStateId":1,
 "relatedEvents":[  ],
 "awsAccountId":"",
 "configurationItemStatus":"ResourceDiscovered",
 "resourceId":"",
 "ARN":"",
 "awsRegion":"",
 "availabilityZone":"",
 "configurationStateMd5Hash":"",
 "resourceType":"",
 "resourceCreationTime":"",
 "tags":{  
    "Name":"db-backup.prod-us.wordeo.com",
    "cirrushq_id":"instance_7701"
 },
 "relationships":[  ],
 "configuration":{  }
   },
   {  },
   {  
 "configurationItemVersion":"1.0",
 "configurationItemCaptureTime":"2014-12-05T10:22:51.751Z",
 "configurationStateId":1,
 "relatedEvents":[  ],
 "awsAccountId":"",
 "configurationItemStatus":"ResourceDiscovered",
 "resourceId":"",
 "ARN":"",
 "awsRegion":"",
 "availabilityZone":"",
 "configurationStateMd5Hash":"",
 "resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
 "resourceCreationTime":"2014-09-29T07:25:44.000Z",
 "tags":{  
    "aws:autoscaling:groupName":"ESND-PROD-US-14-02-14"
 },
 "relationships":[  ],
```

and here is the php

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array(); 
$json =    file_get_contents('C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\test.json'); 

 if($json!=null){ 
$decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
//$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
//$ss=$decode["array"]; 
//echo $decoded['number']; 

if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
{ 
  foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
  //for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

   { 
      $Name=$configurationItems["tags"]["Name"]; 
      echo "Name:",$Name,"<br />"; 

      $cirrushq_id=$configurationItems["tags"]["cirrushq_id"]; 
      echo "cirrushq_id:",$cirrushq_id,"<br />"; 

      $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tag(name, cirrushq_id) VALUES('$Name','$cirrushq_id')")or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));; 

     }// check if row inserted or not 
    if ($result) { 
     // successfully inserted into database 
     $response["code"] = 1; 
     $response["message"] = "successfully stored tags "; 

     // echoing JSON response 
     echo json_encode($response); 
    } else { 
      // failed to insert row 
      $response["code"] = 2; 
      $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 

      // echoing JSON response 
      echo json_encode($response); 
    } 

   } 
 }

?>
```

from the 3rd entry in tags down there is no name or id only

```
aws:autoscaling:groupName":"ESND-PROD-US-14-02-14"
```

I added this line to my php

```
 $awsautoscalinggroupName= $configurationItems["tags"]  ["aws:autoscaling:groupName"];
```

Comment: can you give us some code !

Comment: @simo sure adding now

Comment: Show the whole json please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do in my opinion :

```
1 - Add an extra field to your table (Tag), like 'group_name' or something.
2 - Make All the fields nullable, (name, cirrushq_id, group_name).
```

Edit your php code as follow :

```
$Name= isset($configurationItems["tags"]["Name"]) ? $configurationItems["tags"]["Name"] : ''; 
$cirrushq_id=isset($configurationItems["tags"]["cirrushq_id"]) ? $configurationItems["tags"]["cirrushq_id"] : '';
$group_name=isset($configurationItems["tags"]["aws:autoscaling:groupName"]) ? $configurationItems["tags"]["aws:autoscaling:groupName"] : '';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tag(name, cirrushq_id, group_name) VALUES('$Name','$cirrushq_id', '$group_name')") or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));;
```